# drawing shape following moving object

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, aforge

what I'm trying to do that I connect to my webcam, then detect a colored object(blue patch), and I need to draw rectangle on the form that move with my object's move, but what I get is many rectangles have been drawn with each frame, I need just to keep one rectangle moving with my blue object moving. How to do that?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to really understand what you are doing without seeing any code. I'll assume that you draw the rectangle directly on the Form's Graphics object, and the webcam image is not drawn on this same Form.

If this is so, you should redraw the whole area on the form so that it starts afresh between each frame.

If you are using the paint event of the Form, try clearing the canvas prior to drawing the rectangle:

```
private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

    // Draw rectangle here.
}
```